# SharpDX 3d Camera Rotation clamping Camera y rotation

Tags: c#, 3d, sharpdx

Im trying to make some 3D graphics in C#.

Everything been working out great so far except for one thing.

I want a fps-like camera, that stops when looking down / up.

### I Tried:

- Clamping the "rotationY" variable. (Using MathF.Clamp)
- Clamping the "rotationY" variable. (Using if statements)

None of which worked.

Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
float rotationX = 0;
float rotationY = 0;
float dist = 1;

Window.MouseMove += (s, e) = >
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var yRotate = lastX - e.X;
        var xRotate = lastY - e.Y;
        rotationX += xRotate * moveFactor;
        rotationY += yRotate * moveFactor;
        lastY = e.Y;
        lastX = e.X;

        float h = cos(rotationX) * dist;
        Vector3 cameraTarget = Vector3(cos(rotationY) * h, sin(rotationX) * dist, sin(rotationY) * h);

        viewMatrix = Matrix.LookAtRH(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraTarget, cameraUp);

        updateText();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by Clamping the "rotationX" variable.